# Switch Parent Children relationship in C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Using C# and WPF I have a situation where my data is organized hierarchically.
I am using a treeview to represent this :

- Group_01

  - Object_01

    - Material_01

      - Texture
    - Material_02

      - Texture_02
- Group_02

  - Object_02

    - Material_03

      - Texture_03

I would like to be able to switch the order of the hierarchy, for example be able to create the data starting from the Materials and know all the objects that use that particular material

- Material_02

  - Object_01

    - Group_01
  - Object_02

    - Group_02

What is it the recommended data structure to organize the data? And how I could switch easily between any of these visualizations?

Comment: What data structure are you using right now (for the relationships going in one direction)?

Comment: I am using a TreeListView(for multiselectin and performance), which requires me to have a Children property of every node type that is an ObservableCollection.

Comment: How many nodes? Is the structure going to be edited by the user,  or is it read-only? Do you need many different views - how many - or is it just the regular one plus "upside down" mode?

Comment: Please don't cross-post -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18828959/switch-parent-children-relationship-in-c-sharp. Where do you want the question, here or [so]?

Comment: Sorry I did`t know, a user suggested me to do that so I thought was fine. Maybe On Stack Overflow is better, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To be able to do this, you will need to modify your data type classes so that the `Material` class has a collection of type `Object` and your `Object` class (which is a *really* bad name if this is a custom class) should have a collection of type `Group`. The `Object` class will also need a collection of type `Material` and the `Material` class will also need a collection of type `Texture`, etc.

Then you would need to design a function (with loads of `Linq` or loops) that reverses the hierarchy. The easiest way to do this is if you add properties into your data type classes that relate to each other. Therefore, they should *all* have some kind of `Id` property and then the relevant child classes would need to have `ParentId` properties.

With this setup, you can easily build your hierarchies:

```
Material material = new Material();
material.Id = theIdValue;
material.Textures = new ObservableCollection(allTextTures.Where(t => t.ParentId == 
material.Id).ToList());
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yeah Object is just for description it`s called Mesh in my class.

Answer (score 2):

Since here you have many to many relationships i.e group can have object list which inturn can have material list and the list of groups it belongs to... similarly material can have object list.. so your models should be like below:

```
    public class Group
    {
        ObservableCollection<Object> Objects { get; set; }
    }

    public class Object
    {
        ObservableCollection<Material> Materials { get; set; }
        ObservableCollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    }

    public class Material
    {
        ObservableCollection<Object> Objects { get; set; }
    }
```

Now in order to show the hierarchical data you can use the TreeView to represent this and can define the HierarchicalDataTemplates depending on your number of visualization e.g for GroupHierarchy and MateraialHierarchy you can have templates like:

Group Hierarchy:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="GroupTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Objects}">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding GroupName}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Materials}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ObjectName}"/>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MaterialName}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Material hierarchy:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="MaterialTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Objects}">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding MaterialName}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ObjectName}"/>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding GroupName}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Now you can use `ItemTemplateSelector` to return the correct template for your `TreeView` when you switch the TreeView's `ItemsSource`

Comment: This would be the more suitable and simple solution but I cannot use the Hierarchical data template because with the TreeListView I am using (this one http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30721/WPF-TreeListView-Control) the approach is different. But I need the multiselection and the columns that this control offers.

Answer (score 0):

I would focus on what each object is without focussing on how it will be displayed. What is a node? Looking at your treeview, it looks like a node is an item with various properties - would a filtering system based on numerous categories perhaps work better than a treeview?

Then a user could say I want "material x" with "texture y" but only in "group b" without needing to navigate through a hierachy?

It's hard to give you concrete advice without knowing what a node *actually* represents. Also, might be worth looking at ux.stackexchange.com for front end visualisation ideas.

Comment: Well a node is an entity with several properties, some of this are collections of other types. I thought that hierarchical representation was good to show the relationship else the alternative should be to make n listviews to display each type ex:
Group01 | [Obj_01,Obj_02] | [Mat_01, Mat_02] | Tex_01 but since there is too much branching it would result in a poor display.

Comment: btw what is it ux.stackexchange.com ? (I can`t access the link)

Comment: http://ux.stackexchange.com/ is for questions on ux and data visualisation questions (like this one) would fit in quite nicely I think